# Handling optional query parameters in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I have a service accepting query parameters which are optional. I get following error when I call this service.

> fatal error: cannot find key 'schoolId' error: error, message: cannot
>   find key 'schoolId'   at
>   guide:studentInfo.getStudentBySearch(student_info.bal:91)

Following is my code. How can I safely check if specific query parameters are passed and proceed on these conditions?

```
    @http:ResourceConfig {
        methods: ["GET"],
        path: "/*"
    }
    getStudentBySearch(endpoint client, http:Request req) {

            http:Response response;

            var params = req.getQueryParams();
            var schoolId = <string>params.schoolId;
            var addmissionYear = <string>params.addmissionYear;
    ..
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"req.getQueryParams()" returns a map[1]. In that case you can any map functions[2] for your needs.

You can use the "hasKey" function to check if a query parameter exists or not.

Example:

```
map params = request.getQueryParams();
if (params.hasKey("schoolId")) {
    string schoolId = <string>params["schoolId"];
    // Handle here
} else {
    // Handle here
}
```

[1] - https://ballerina.io/swan-lake/learn/by-example/query-path-matrix-param.html
[2] - https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/lang.map/index.html

Comment: Interesting thing with maps. When I do
`req.getQueryParams()["foo"] + " bar"`

I get this interesting compilation error:
`operator '+' not defined for 'string' and 'string?'`
Evidently the map lookup is returning a **string?** instead of a **string** . I can't find any documentation about this, but would assume it's some Option analog. Don't see any methods on it.

Having a `.or` or .`orElse` on it would be more functional than the multiple lines of imperative code above....

Comment: Found the Optional documentation -> https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/optional-type.html but this really doesn't explain much about using an Optional type, just it's existence.

Comment: For the completeness sake, in Ballerina optional type is just a short hand for a union of expected type and nil. That is string? is (string | ()). That's why there are no .or/.orElese like methods defined on it. But there is language constructs to help handle nillable types (another name for optional). Please refer https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/by-example/elvis-operator.html and https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/by-example/optional-field-access.html